# Any way to force cellular network refresh?

Tags: cellular-radio

Cellular coverage where I live is very spotty, to the effect I can essentially draw lines on a map and say "on this side, I probably have coverage, while on the other side I almost certainly don't". Naturally, crossing one of these lines (almost always) results in losing coverage.

The inverse, unfortunately, is not true; once I lose coverage, it takes several minutes before I have a cellular connection again, even if I've been in an area that *should* have coverage.

Switching into and back out of airplane mode almost always gets the connection back sooner.

Now... this actually makes sense. IIUC, trying to get a connection, especially if coverage is poor, takes power, and so to conserve battery, once connectivity is lost, phones implement a delay before trying again. Whereas coming out of airplane mode, the phone obviously hasn't been trying at all, and it would normally be the case that coverage is available and you don't want to wait several minutes before trying to establish a connection. Thus, the 'toggle airplane mode hack' overrides the usual delay between connection attempts.

IIRC it's also possible to fiddle with the network settings in order to make the phone try for a connection more frequently, but I don't want it wasting power if I'm actually sitting somewhere that has poor/no coverage. I also don't like the airplane mode 'trick' because it's slow and disconnects other networks that I might be using.

Is there another way to make an Android phone try to reconnect to cellular service "now"? (If it matters, I have Android 13 with Samsung One UI 5.1.)